# WooCommerce: renaming of a single variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Wordpress 6.2.2
WooCommerce 7.7.0

I want to rename (not change) the variation "Blue" of property "Color" to "Navy".

I can't handle it manually as there are too many products in my shop. I would rather not use (or even pay) for third party bulk plugins. SQL must be enough.

So far, I did the following on my test database:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value="Navy" WHERE `meta_key` LIKE '%_color' AND meta_value='Blue';
SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy like '%color%';# picked the id
UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET description = 'Navy Blue' WHERE term_id = 'term-id-from-above';
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_wc_term_counts_%';
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_timeout_wc_term_counts_%';
```

But somehow that does not help.

I am not familiar with all the relations between the tables. Can somebody please help.

Comment: Go to Products -> Attributes -> Colors  and rename it ?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this only helps with the standard post type not with (my) custom post type.

Comment: You cant rename taxonomy term ? I hardly thinks so.

Answer (score 0):

I did some reverse engineering. I changed the color attribute and some products manually and compared the SQL dumps before and afterward.

This is what I found out.

**Important: Don't risk your database if you don't know what you are doing. And: backup, backup, backup!**

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE slug like '%blue%' ORDER BY slug;
```

Manually change name and slug to “Navy” resp. “navy”. That's the renaming of the variation Blue to Navy of Attribute color.

Now we still habe to change it in the already existing products. You can check this here:

```
SELECT * from wp_postmeta  WHERE meta_key LIKE '%format%' AND meta_value = 'blue';

CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta_backup AS SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta; # create a fast backup

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'Navy' WHERE meta_key = 'attribute_format' AND meta_value = 'Blue'; # Step 1

SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_product_attributes' AND meta_value LIKE '%Blue%'; # check

SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_product_attributes' AND meta_value LIKE '%Blue%'; # get all the possible distinct results

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, 'Blue', 'Navy') WHERE meta_value LIKE '%BLue%'; # Step 2
```

Now comes a very significant point. WooCommerce stores the product attributes as a serialized array.

> a:1:{s:6:"format";a:7:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Format";s:5:"value";s:8:"Red|Blue";s:8:"position";i:0;s:10:"is_visible";i:1;s:12:"is_variation";i:1;s:11:"is_taxonomy";i:0;s:6:"_price";s:4:"0.49";}}

You have to make sure that the s-value (in this example “s:8”) is changed to the proper new value. We don't have to change it here because the string “Blue” and “Navy” have the same length.

But if you chose “Darkblue” as the new color caption, you would change it like this.

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(meta_value, ';s:8:', ';s:12:') WHERE meta_value LIKE '%Darkblue%'; # Step 3
```

That's it. After this method, all your products variations of “Blue” are changed to “Navy” where all the other attributes price, availability, stock, SKU and so on stay the same.